# Sync Native Calendar (Galaxy S3) with Windows Live Calendar

Tags: calendar, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I currently have a Galaxy S3 unrooted with the shipped ROM. I am attempting to sync the native Calendar App with Windows Live Calendar.

I can see under the Calendar list that my @live.com calendars are there, however when selecting the correct calendar to sync to and adding the event it doesn't appear on the web.

Are there any additional settings that need to be modified (previously I have only ever synced with a Google account which seemed a lot easier)?

Comment: Have you tried adding a "Corporate" account in Android and entering Exchange settings manually? (I'm not sure live.com offers this but I know Google does, and uses this as a workaround on iPhones)